# Regex expression looking at multiple scenarios of a number

Tags: regex

Good day, I am struggling to pick out a number that is sometimes preceded by some characters but never by others.
Here is an example:
The number I am looking for is always 8 digits long and some time preceded by ABC

```
12345678 
ABC12345678
abc12345678
abc 12345678
ABC 12345678
```

I have this working well but now I need to specify that if the number is preceded by `XYZ-` it must be ignored.
So in this sentence:
`XYZ-87654321` is next to `ABC12345678` (or any of the above mentioned).
I only want to return `12345678`.

This is what I have tried but it returns nothing, if I remove the and at the end it returns both.

```
((?<!\.)((?<=\D)|(?<=^))\d{8}((?=\D)|(?=$))(?!\.)|(?:([A-a][B-b][C-c]))\d{8}|(?:([A-a][B-b][C-c]))\s\d{8})&(?!:[X-x][Y-y][Z-z][-]\d{8})
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add your own attempts.

Comment: You said you have something that almost works well. Can you edit your question and share your current code so we would not have to start over from 0?

Comment: Is it that the letters that precede the number may have a dash, a space or nothing between them and the number? ie `ABC-12345678`, `ABC 12345678` or `ABC12345678`? Should `DEF12345678` match? Is it only `XYZ` that would not match? Please clarify.

Comment: What about `XABC12345678`, `ABC.12345678`, `ABC_12345678`, `ABC1234567890123`, `/ABC12345678`, `ABC12345678A`, ... The rules are not clear.

Comment: Your convoluted regex is equal to `(?i)((?<![.\d])\d{8}(?![\d.])|abc\s?\d{8})&(?!:xyz-\d{8})`. What is it supposed to match? What is wrong with it? If you need to add an exception, then add a lookbehind - you seem to know what it is, you use a lot of them in your regex, and test and let us know what the problem is.

Comment: Using `[A-a]` matches [more](https://regex101.com/r/7g8yvZ/1) than `[Aa]`, the ampersand in your regex matches `&` which is not in the example data. If it should not be **preceded** then you should use a negative lookbehind `(?<!` and place it before matching the digits. But what does this mean "a number that is sometimes preceded by some characters but never by others" ? If you only allow an optional ABC, then you don't have to exclude `XYZ-` at all like `(?<!\S)(?:abc\s*)?(\d{8})\b(?!\.)` see https://regex101.com/r/5uz1Zy/1

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this which returns the correct matches.

(?i)((?!:xyz-\d{8})&(?<![.\d])\d{8}(?![\d.])|abc?.\s?\d{8})|(\s\d{8}\s)